# Mysterious Step in a Float-to-Int Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

In reverse-engineering an old music format I've encountered a conversion algorithm that converts a 14-bit unsigned floating-point value to an 11-bit integer value. The algorithm is as follows (pvf is the 14-bit floating-point value):

```
i87 = ((pvf >> 8) * 8) // 7
m = (((i87 & 0x7) + 7) << 8) | (pvf & 0xff)
e = (~i87 & 0x38) >> 3
p = m >> e
```

After playing with it some I've discovered that for the relevant values [0,56*256) this is equivalent to:

```
m = (pvf % 0x700) + 0x700 # Mantissa with hidden bit
e = 7 - (pvf // 0x700)
p = m >> e
```

This algorithm is... mysterious. It's obviously a floating-point to integer conversion, shifting a mantissa by an exponent. Where things get strange is the encoding of the high byte. The basic format is 00pppppp mmmmmmmm. When p is multiplied by 8/7 (and m is left alone) this produces 00eeennn mmmmmmmm with n being the high bits of the mantissa. In other words, rather than e getting 3 bits and n getting 3, n gets log2(7) = ~2.8 bits (n can be 0-6 but not 7) and e is mixed in with it. But WHY? On the architecture this is implemented on this is DRASTICALLY slower than simply allocating a full 3 bits to e and n, so there must be some good reason for it.

The only clue is exactly what this format is used for. Note frequencies are stored in this format, and the resulting p is the period value written to hardware where

```
Hz = 1789773 // (16 * (p + 1))
```

I note that the algorithm does NOT subtract 1 from p, which I suspect to be a bug. This appears to be done to piecewise-approximate linear pitch slides/vibrato, as relative pitch (an integer) is added to the floating-point value BEFORE conversion. But how does that relate to the 8/7 multiplier?

As examples:

- 0x375c: 0x37 * 8/7 = 0x3e: 0x3e5c (111110 01011100) with e = 7 - 7 = 0 and n = 6 + 7 = 0xd (the hidden bit). p = 0xd5c >> 0 = 0xd5c (32.70 Hz ~= C1).
- 0x14: 0x14 (00010100) with e = 7 - 0 = 7 and n = 0 + 7 = 7. p = 0x714 >> 7 = 0xe (7457 Hz ~= A#8; actually supposed to be B8, but the p off by one bug is causing severe detuning at high frequencies).

Comment: How sure are you that a binary (?) floating-point format is being used? Please provide the 14-bit floating-point format. How are the 14 bits allocated to constituent parts? Does it use sign-magnitude convention or twos-complement convention? Re "A frequency value of 0x375c corresponds to 32.69 Hz ... while 0x14 corresponds to 7457 Hz": This is quite confusing. Are these "frequency values" stored in the 14-bit floating-point format? I assume `//` denotes integer division with rounding-toward-zero?

Comment: @njuffa The p = m >> e makes it clear that it's a floating point format. There is no provision for negative numbers as far as I can tell (it's never used in any way that would require them, either). And yeah, // is Python integer division. The basic format is 00pppppp mmmmmmmm. p * 8/7 produces 00eeennn, giving a mantissa of 1nnn mmmmmmmm. The mystery is why p has to be unpacked rather than just making the top byte 00eeennn directly.

Comment: Obrantz So `pppppp` represents a six-bit exponent field which encodes a power of two? Is the exponent biased as in IEEE754 or stored as twos complement? Usually when doing these reverse-engineering exercises it is useful to see how 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, are encoded in the floating-point format. Could you add that information?

Comment: Rewrote it with answers to those questions.

Comment: What is your answerable programming question?

Comment: @greybeard Apparently during the edits I ended up removing a clear statement of the question: WHY does it only allocate 10.8 bits to the mantissa? What logical reason is there to do it in such a computationally expensive way?

Comment: I find this much too vague. What are the *relevant values*, and how do you know? Please quote/disclose the manifestation of the conversion algorithm *encountered* that you are working from.

Comment: One effect using a "base" of 0x700 rather than 0x1000 is to give eee more range. But in `e = (~i87 & 0x38) >> 3`, the 8 and 9 possible would be masked to 0 and 1.

Comment: (*DRASTICALLY slower* Where division is significantly slower than multiplication, division *by a constant* should be replaced by multiplication with the inverse.)

Comment: @greybeard This is an 8-bit processor from the 80s. It doesn't have multiply either. It doesn't even have a barrel shifter :P

Comment: Did you make a plot of all possible `pvf` --> `Hz` mappings, maybe also to `log(Hz/440)/log(2) * 12` to get semi-tones above/below "a". I suspect you don't have a pure floating point format here, but a "clever" way to encode different frequencies.

Comment: @chtz Period is approximately 14.317e^0.0004pvf with R^2 = 0.9999. Frequency is approximately 7813.2e^-0.0004pvf, with the same R^2. It's definitely floating-point and (as such) values are a piecewise linear approximation of an exponential curve (i.e. linear pitch).